# String manipulation overlapping

Tags: string, python-3.x, overlap

```
def Codehelp(st):
    i = 0
    noot = ""
    while i < len(st):
        if st[i] == '$':
            noot += "**" + st[i] + "**"
        i += 1
    if '$' in noot:
        return noot
    else:
        return "**"
    return
```

Basically, every time user inputs a string that has '$' in it, the code will return only the '$' with 2 asterisks before and after the '$'. In most test cases the code runs fine, however once inputting a string with more than one '$', i.e. `Codehelp("r$t$$")`, it outputs `**$****$****$**` (add two * to both the beginning and end of the string), instead of `****$**$**` (ignore the first two *).

Answer (score 0):

Well like you say I get this output: `**$****$****$**`.
I can certainly say that this makes sense because it only checks on the current instance of `$` and adds `**` before and after.
If you want it to be more "intelligent", you might need to implement something that might peek ahead to see if there is another `$` after the current one.

However, to get `**$$` (not sure it that is what you expect, please correct me), you need to look at the next index to see if there is another `$` (obviously taking string length boundary checks into consideration as well) and not add additional `**` after the second `$`.